# Map classes of one ontology to individuals of another

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I need to map classes from a preexisting ontology to individuals in mine. I'm looking for an elegant way to do so. For instance, let's say the preexisting ontology has:

```
Class Drug1 with subclasses Brand1, Brand2, Brand3
```

In my ontology, I want to have `Brand1, Brand2, and Brand3 as individuals of Class Drug1`.

I cannot use `owl:sameAs` because it is for individual-individual mapping. Similarly, I probably cannot use `equivalentClass` becuase it is for class-class mapping.

What is a good approach to take in such a scenario?

Comment: The semantics of `owl:sameAs` is that the resources have all of the same properties and values.  This works for any URI, including classes.  `owl:equivalentClass` has very different semantics.  It means that the classes have exactly the same set of individuals (i.e. the exact same class members).

Comment: But is it a good practice to use owl:sameAs for classes? I was under the impression that it's supposed to be used only for equating individuals.

Comment: It depends on what you want.  If you want to make sure the classes have the same properties, then use `owl:sameAs` (a perfectly valid, albeit unusual, use case for class definitions).  If you want to make sure the classes have the same members (individuals), then use `owl:equivalentClass`.

Comment: I think that there was a question about this relatively recently. Even though you can use punning here, note that reasoners will see the classes and the individuals as completely separate, even though they're identified by the same IRI. You don't get any special reasoning like "here's an individual that has members" or "here's a class that has object property values".

Comment: I remember reading something along similar lines. Do you have suggestions on what an elegant solution is?

Answer (score 0):

It's done by punning. In Protege, just have identical names for the class and the individual you'd like to pun.